# how to load external source to iframe instead of download?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe where i try to put a link in the src. the src is to a html file that is normally being downloaded from the server to the file system, but i now want to show it in the iframe instead. is there a way to force an iframe to load whatever it gets in the src instead of downloading it??

edit:

i'm using jquery,

```
$('#webinfo').attr( "src", path);
```

where webinfo is my iframe. when I load this it puts the html file the path is pointing at in my download folder instead of displaying it in my iframe.
this is my definition of the iframe.

```
<div id="webdiv">
    <iframe class="webdivSetup" id="webinfo" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

and my css

```
#webdiv{
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
.webdivSetup{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: if you set SRC attribute of IFRAME to URL your of your HTML - it should display in the IFRAME. How are u doing it and what is not working?

Comment: This question doesn't quite make sense. How do you define load vs download?

Comment: I think he wants to display the contents of the download in the iFrame, like opening and displaying a PDF file in the iFrame, instead of downloading it.

Comment: editet my question instead.

Comment: Can you show your html which you are putting in your iframe? and how are you generating that html ? And what is the value of `path` variable you are putting ?

Comment: The HTML i put in is kinda secret. But there is nothing special about it. It's like a normal link but to a local server etc. localhost:port//app/id/index.html