# iframe downloading HTML file instead of displaying but works on local drive

Tags: html, aem

good morning. I have an iframe on my CQ5 website and it's very basic, src = "path to content folder which contains an html file.html" I see the Iframe has a blank grayish white box in it however, it does not display the content. It tried to download the file instead! I have tested this code on my local drive and it works perfectly. What the heck is going on here? There is a similar question that I found on: **[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947320/how-to-load-external-source-to-iframe-instead-of-download#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947320/how-to-load-external-source-to-iframe-instead-of-download#_=_)** CQ5 is kind of like a wordpress type development tool.

Any ideas? please help.

Comment: Does your server return the correct Content-Type (it should be text/html) in the response headers ?

Comment: I am new to the idea of headers, can you give me an example of how to locate them and modify them?

Comment: Well, if you have Firefox, install Firebug : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ (restart Firefox if needed) then open your website and press F12 it should open the Firebug panel, go to the Net panel and reload your website, everything that is loaded by your website should appear on the list. From there you need to find the right content (look at the URL) open it and look at the headers. Here is an example : http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1425499640.png

Comment: Thatnks for that I have located the headers.what should the headers be set to to display an html file within a iframe?

Comment: It should be text/html, if it is not that would explain why the browser try to download it.